# Product of Sinusoids: Sum of Frequencies (proof)

Tags: trigonometry

In this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_frequency#Applications

they write:

"the product of two complex sinusoids is also a complex sinusoid whose frequency is the sum of the original frequencies."

I am looking for a proof of this. Could someone please give me this proof of point me to a document that would have it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is just the power law $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$.  Or, $\exp(j\omega t)\exp(j\phi t)=\exp(j(\omega+\phi)t)$

Comment: thank you. I appreciate your quick answer.